# How to add caret only to selected column in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a table and I want to display caret only for the column selected. rest of the column should not display caret until it has been clicked
 Select
 Identifier

Comment: Can you show relevant code to support your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar. I use fontawesome for caret. When customer selects column name the caret changes and `sortType` is set to that column name

```
<th class="text-center text-nowrap">
    <a (click)="onSort('Name')" style="cursor: pointer;">
        Customer Name
        <span *ngIf="sortType == 'Name' && sortAD == 'Asc'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span *ngIf="sortType == 'Name' && sortAD == 'Desc'" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
        <span *ngIf="sortType != 'Name'" class="fa fa-sort"></span>
    </a>
</th>

onSort(columnName: string): void {
        if (this.sortAD === 'Asc' && this.sortType === columnName) {
            this.sortAD = 'Desc';
        }
        else {
            this.sortAD = 'Asc';
        }
        this.sortType = columnName;
}
```